# RampTo Filter frequency value in Tone.js

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

This may be a silly question as I am new to Tone.js, but is it possible to rampTo the frequency value of a lowpass Filter?
I'm trying to make a real-time interactive work that needs to ramp the lowpass to a value (x).
I have tried a few different things but none seem to work. Things like synth.volume.rampTo(x,t) work nicely, but I can't seem to make it work for the Filter component.

for example, I have tried to pass in a Signal as the frequency value, as the Signal class has methods like .rampTo. Is this correct? How should i be doing this?

```
var lowPassFreq = new Tone.Signal(300, Tone.Frequency);

var lowPass = new Tone.Filter(
    {
        "type":"lowpass",
        "frequency":lowPassFreq.value           
    }
).toMaster();

var noiseSynth = new Tone.NoiseSynth().connect(lowPass);

this.playSound = function (x){

    noiseSynth.triggerAttack("4n");

    lowPassFreq.rampTo(x, 0.05)
    lowPass.frequency.value = lowPassFreq.value

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but you can try `lowPass.frequency.linearRampToValueAtTime(value, time)` with appropriate values for `value` and `time`.  This will change the frequency (cutoff) of the filter linearly from its current value to the new `value`.

Comment: ahhh thanks Raymond. The problem was i was trying to use lowPass.frequency.value.rampTo(), which was getting an error. Which is why i was trying to pass thru the lowPassFreq signal... Sorry for the noob moment!

Comment: Glad it worked since I wasn't sure what you were trying to do.  Everybody's a noob at some point!